# Deleting values with more than 2 decimal place in array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array with chunks of values.

```
$value = array(
              array(3075,15,461.25,16,535.05),
              array(3075,15,461.25808,16,535.05),//to be removed
              array(3075,15,461.2,16,535.05234)//to be removed
              );
```

I need to remove the rows that has values with more than 2 decimal places. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strlen(substr(strrchr($x, "."), 1))` to count the decimals and `array_filter` to remove any array value with more than 2 decimals

```
$value = array(
        array(3075,15,461.25,16,535.05),
        array(3075,15,461.25808,16,535.05),//to be removed
        array(3075,15,461.2,16,535.05234)//to be removed
);

$value = array_filter($value,
    function ($v) {
        foreach ($v as $x) {
            if (strlen(substr(strrchr($x, "."), 1)) > 2)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

var_dump($value);
```

Output

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => int 3075
      1 => int 15
      2 => float 461.25
      3 => int 16
      4 => float 535.05
```

Comment: As `strrchr(461.25)` results in `.25` you can directly take the `strlen` of the result. So `if (strlen(strrchr($x, ".")) > 3)` will work.

Comment: @WouterH  yes it will . there no no one way of catching a rat

Comment: and why would you do a `substr()` when it's not needed? To slow it down a little bit? ;)

Comment: `to count the decimals` ??? `.05` ?? wanted `05` in case it needs to be returned .. and talking about  `To slow it down a little bit` ?? you need to do your benchmark again ....

Comment: With substr: 19ms for array with 1 million elements. Without substr: 13ms. hehe, but you're right, better to check the real portion.

Comment: Funny... its a blank screen when i test it out. But it showed no error since i used error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: The server is using PHP version 5.2.17

Comment: `PHP 5.2.17` does not support closures .. this would work for you http://3v4l.org/IfDEO