# Deleting empty array elements

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have just been shown the method to remove numbers with more than 2 decimal places from an array [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325238/deleting-values-with-more-than-2-decimal-place-in-array).
The thing is when i try to format the output using echo instead of var_dump as such:

```
$line = 1;
for($i = 1; $i < count($value1); $i++){
    echo "$line | ".$value1[$i][0]." | ".$value1[$i][1]." | ".$value1[$i][2]." | ".$value1[$i][3]." | ".$value1[$i][4].'<br>';
    $line = $line + 1;
}
```

I get many "Notice: Undefined offset: " all over the place. Is there a way to reset the rows in the array?

The reason i need to format it with "echo" is so that i can copy the output directly and paste it into a document without having to delete the unnecessary characters from "var_dump". Am i doing it wrong?

Thanx in advance...

Thanx in advance.

Comment: The proper way to loop over an array depends on the contents and structure of the particular array. So...what's in your array? Use var_dump() and format the output nicely for us.

Answer (score 2):

What about using implode instead of the unhandy concatenation?

```
<?php
foreach ($value1 as $counter => $line){
    echo ($counter + 1) . " | ". implode(" | ", $line) . '<br>';
}
```

This way, it's ensured that only existing values are concatenated. If you still want to remove elements from an array, you might consider checking them for emptyness and using [unset](http://php.net/manual/de/function.unset.php) after that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the array looks like, but one error you are having in your code for sure is:

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($value1); $i++)
```

in PHP an array starts with the index `0`, you need to correct your code like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($value1); $i++)
```

or use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) which is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.
After the:

```
function decimalFilter($v) {
        foreach ( $v as $x ) {
            if (strlen(substr(strrchr($x, "."), 1)) > 2)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
$value = array_filter($value, "decimalFilter");
```

Then i add:

```
sort($value);
```

followed by:

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($value); $i++){
    echo $value[$i][0]." | ".$value[$i][1]." | ".$value[$i][2]." | ".$value[$i][3]." | ".$value[$i][4].'<br>';
}
```

The missing elements disappeared during output. Thing is i dunno if this is a practical approach as yet.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a few ways to either remove or ignore the array elements without PHP throwing notices:

```
$line = 1;
for($i = 1; $i < count($value1); $i++){
if( isset( $value[$i][0]) === TRUE && isset( $value[$i][1]) === TRUE && isset( $value[$i][2]) === TRUE && isset( $value[$i][3]) === TRUE && isset( $value[$i][4]) === TRUE )
{
    echo "$line | ".$value1[$i][0]." | ".$value1[$i][1]." | ".$value1[$i][2]." | ".$value1[$i][3]." | ".$value1[$i][4].'<br>';
}

    $line = $line + 1;
}
```

or you could use count($value[$i][0]) > 0 to ensure the array has a value contained.